# java heap memory issue in IBM AIX server

Tags: java, heap-memory

getting below error in IBM AIX server "JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9gc23(2): Failed to instantiate heap.  3584M requested" how to resolve the proble ? i want to increase the heap menmory up to 10gb

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a 32-bit JVM? If so you could run into the maximum allocatable space, 4G

Answer (score 0):

We can  check heap size by java `-XshowSettings:vm -version` . Use the below command if you want to set a different heap size.

```
export IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx<some_value>m
```

Ref : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21224215

I hope it will be helpful to others if not to the person who have asked the question 7 years ago.